# How can I uninstall MercurialEclipse manually on eclipse 3.6

Tags: eclipse, plugins, mercurial

I installed MercurialEclipse 1.4.1286 on eclipse 3.6 on MacOSX.
And I wanted to upgrade to MercurialEclipse 1.7 from http://cbes.javaforge.com/update.
Since the update is not shown when I use "Check for updates", I have to uninstall the old one and install 1.7 from new update site.

The MercurialEclipse 1.4 is not shown in the installed software list. So I manuall deleted it from /eclipse/plugin and /eclipse/features

The I install newer version from the url, but eclipse says:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: MercurialEclipse 1.7.1.v201012101420 (mercurialeclipse.feature.group 1.7.1.v201012101420)
  Software currently installed: com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse 1.4.1286 (com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse.feature.group 1.4.1286)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    MercurialEclipse 1.4.1286 (com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse 1.4.1286)
    com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse 1.7.1.v201012101420
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse 1.4.1286 (com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse.feature.group 1.4.1286)
    To: com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse [1.4.1286]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: MercurialEclipse 1.7.1.v201012101420 (mercurialeclipse.feature.group 1.7.1.v201012101420)
    To: com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse [1.7.1.v201012101420]
```

I searched the /eclipse directory and removed all mercurial related strings and files but it doesn't work.

Anyone know how to uninstall MercurialEclipse manually?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for `com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse_1.8.1.201104101049.jar` in your eclipse installation folder and remove it. Looks to me that is the easy way to remove this plugin.

Comment: Should you need to uninstall plugins on Ecipse Indigo Service Release 1:
Go to menu Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details. There you can uninstall.

Comment: hi5... perfect... never knew uninstalling a plugin could be so easy :P

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why, but after remove some Installation Histories, the mercurialEclipse plugin reappeared in the installed software tab. unintall it all is well now.